# How can I make SQLite work on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10

Yo,

So I've been developing a Universal Windows Store app in Visual Studio 2013 on one machine, and wanted to continue developing it on an another machine running Windows 10 Technical Preview.

The problem is that in Visual Studio 2015 Preview there is a new C++ Redistributable package version (2015), and the latest SQLite requires version 2013, so that particular reference is missing. I can build the project, it deploys successfully, but there is an exception saying it can't load sqlite3.dll. I'm assuming this is because of the missing Visual C++ Redistributable Package 2013. I tried downloading it, but the entry is still missing from the Add reference dialog under Extensions, where it is seen on VS 2013.

Any experience of making it work? Any insider info on when SQLite will work for Windows 10?

Cheers

Comment: I also have the same problem, have you managed to make it work?

Answer (score 8):

Yesterday I blogged about how to get [SQLite working with Windows 10 Universal apps](http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/)

It's really simple and comes down to [using a pre-release version of SQLite Visual Studio extension](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), and then just using whatever library or ORM you used before.

Note that Windows 10 Universal apps will also be capable of using Entity Framework 7, which can be used with almost any DB provider including SQLite.

EDIT: The Visual Studio extension is not in *pre-release* as of build 10240.

Comment: This pre-release (nor a final) version is no longer showing up on their download page. Any idea what to do now?

Comment: @earthling since VS is not longer in prerelease, just search on that same link for "Universal App Platform" and there will be a link for "sqlite-uap-3081101.vsix".

Comment: Thanks, they didn't have it yesterday which was frustrating but I see it posted today.

Answer (score 4):

SQLite for Universal App Platform is now available as pre-release

[Sqlite download page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

so after searching on the web a little i came across this

Seems that some (not very wise) software install incompatible sqlite3.dll to the windows system folder.
Check your `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` folder for `sqlite3.dll` and rename it to `sqlite3-backup.dll`.

If some other software can't start after it, just put sqlite3-backup.dll to the folder where main .exe resides and rename it to sqlite3.dll.

Also check registry key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs`.

If sqlite3.dll value is present - remove it. This registry key is designed only for system dlls, not for third-party dlls.

Hopefully rhis helps. I was thinking its a windows UAC system which requires you to run app as admin etc.. il keep searching but dp update if this fixes the issue

Comment: There was no DLL related to SQLite in my SysWOW64 folder.
Also there was no entry for it in the registry either :(

Comment: Yes, this didn't work for me either.  I can install the WinRT package from the SQLite website, but it won't show up in the "add reference" dialogs.  I didn't find sqlite3.dll in my syswow64 dir, either.

Answer (score 2):

Add **reference** Runtime C++ 2013 package for Windows. That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Referencing a Windows 8.1 SqlLite requires referencing new “Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows Universal” extension. You can add using Add Reference dialog in a Universal Windows app.

That should fix the runtime exception.