# Create internal DB in a UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Is it possible to create a "internal" database to use with a UWP?
So when i publish the app it comes with the db, because there is no need for me to use a db on lets say Azure.

In the app i show movies and the user can store a movie to favorites. So I only need to store the index number from that movie to use next time a user navigate to the favorites.

Or maybe there is a better way, like a text file?
I cant find any information regarding this and a tip would be much appreciated! :D

Comment: You're only going to store a key (id) for the movie, correct? Database probably is overkill and not the first place I would start. I'd store the value in a text file and, if necessary for some reason, encrypt the list of movie Ids. If you need more power / capabilities, consider a database. This could change depending on where the rest of the movie details are coming form. If that's in a local datastore (database, xml file, etc.) I'd considering stuffing this list in that datastore.

Comment: That was my tought aswell, then just use streamReader to get all the id´s right?

Comment: Yes, read the text file using a streamreader. Keep it simple until it no longer meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your input much appreciated! Case closed! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have solved your case by using a text file instead of a db.
For the sake of detail :

If the text file doesn't meet your criteria further on you should probably use Sqlite. There's a preview version currently in development.

For more details :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30001048/4487530

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good alteretiv! I Accept your awnser so the thread is propeply closed.. :)